# Xamarin.Android Development Errors: APT2260, APT2062 or Red Lines in MainActivity.cs

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am encountering several issues while developing a Xamarin application. I haven't touched this app a few months and now suddenly I only have the problems with Android. Sometimes the errors APT2260 and APT2062 occur the next try a few lines in MainActivity.cs are red (even using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android; -> only Android is red), making troubleshooting challenging. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve the following problems:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(3,3): Error APT2260: resource style/MainTheme.Base (aka com.companyname.bizztimeapp:style/MainTheme.Base) not found. (APT2260) (BIZZTIMEAPP.Android)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(3,3): Error APT2062: failed linking references. (APT2062) (BIZZTIMEAPP.Android)
```

I've to mention that on iOS it still works perfectly and I never changed the MainTheme.

My styles.xml in the Directory BIZZTIMEAPP.Android/Resources/values looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <!-- As of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 the theme has moved into the Forms binary -->
    <!-- If you want to override anything you can do that here. -->
    <!-- Underneath are a couple of entries to get you started. -->

    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>-->
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>-->
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <!--<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>-->
  </style>
</resources>
```

Same on VS for Mac and on Visual Studio on Windows.

Tried so many suggested solutions but nothing worked for me till now. (everything is up-to-date)

Comment: Didn't this problem come up before? Have you made any changes to your code?

Comment: You can first try to delete the obj folders and bin folders, then rebuild it. If the problem persist, could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: I had several problems, maybe I already had that one before too. But this time I am not able to solve it. And yes, I already tried things like deleting the obj and bin folders, cleaning and rebuilding or doing a dotnet restore. Normally these things solve xamarins "special issues". No I haven't made any changes to my code. I also jumped back to a way older commit in my git history to test this. I also tried to create a new project, then I copied all necessary files into it and the error was still there....

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or more code snippets so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT: I'm running into the same issue. It seems to just be caused by upgrading an old project to the latest version of Xamarin Forms. I don't explicitly have `MainTheme.Base` defined in my project (and doesn't look like I ever did). Other values for `parent` I've found online, like `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, also don't seem to work.  Even copying `MainTheme.Base` from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Resources/values/styles.xml#L28C78-L28C78) fails because `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar` cannot be found.

Comment: I also tried both of the "AppCompat" packages on Nuget, with no luck.  Looks like downgrading is the only option.

Answer (score 3):

I started encountering this yesterday too.

In my case it was the seemingly-minor NuGet upgrade of Xamarin Forms from

5.0.0.2578 to 5.0.0.2612

Visual Studio Mac v17.6.3

Verified on two different Macs with different Android devices and OS versions as the target!

The interesting thing is that it didn't bother a TestRunner project in the same solution. Only affected the Shell GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I also tried it by downgrading my Xamarin.Forms Package but it didn't run either. Still two errors on these lines: 
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
error: APP.Android/MainActivity.cs(13,13): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Platform' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Essentials' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (APP.Android)
By the way I have VS for Mac v17.6.4 (build 472)

Comment: The Xamarin.Essentials missing Platform is a different error. In my case I also downgraded that from 1.8.0 to 1.7.5.  Sorry, did that at different time and didn't think of it with relation to this issue.

Comment: Incredibly, this issue still exists **four months** later with v5.0.0.2622. Downgrading to Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2578 worked, though like the above user, I had to also downgrade Xamarin Essentials from 1.8.2 to 1.7.7